# Use table force drop when you have two tables refrencing each other

Tags: sql-server, referential-integrity

I created table `A` and table `B`

I am using SQL Server and I got this error message:

> ```
> Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Could not drop object 'a' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
> Msg 3726, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> Could not drop object 'b' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    no INT IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    aaa NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE b(
    no INT IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    bbb NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    
);
```

And these are my reference constraint for these table

```
ALTER TABLE a ADD FOREIGN KEY (no) REFERENCES b(no);
ALTER TABLE b ADD FOREIGN KEY (no) a(no);
```

but I tried the following methods to force drop to table a, b then failed

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE a;
DROP TABLE b;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
DROP TABLE ENERGY.D_CORROSION_COUNT_1 CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
DROP TABLE ENERGY.D_CORROSION_COUNT_2 CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE;
```

Comment: So which is it? MySql, or SQL Server (it *looks* like MSSQL)?  And what is the exact error message?

Comment: i happend in mssql and i added error message

Comment: The best way to handle this situation is to just write a script which deletes the records which are referencing each other, then drop the table.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/

Comment: tkx too much!!!